# Remove duplicates from rows in mydataset

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, rows, data-cleaning

Im having a CSV file which contain 436 columns and 14k rows.
The format of the data inside the cells is string.
For the example it looks like this:

```
A,A,A,B,B,C,C,,,,,
D,F,D,F,D,F,H,,,,,
```

My goal is to get every row with its unique values only. Like that:

```
A,B,C,,,,,,,,
D,F,H,,,,,,,,
```

The file is on csv/txt file. I can use Jupyter notebook( with Python3 or any other code you guys will provide). But this is my enviorment of work. Any help would be amazing! 
I also uploaded the csv as a Dataframe to the notebook. What you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read your csv file into a numpy array. Then for each row, I'd do something like:

```
import numpy as np
s='A,A,A,B,B,C,C'
f=s.split(',')
np.unique(np.array(f))
```

which prints `array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='|S1')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the csv loaded as a dataframe `df`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   A   A   A   B   B   C   C
1   D   F   D   F   D   F   H
```

Iterate over rows and find the unique values per each row:

```
unique_vals = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    unique_vals.append(row.unique().tolist())
unique_vals

[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'F', 'H']]
```

You haven't mentioned the return data type so I've returned a list.

Edit: If the data set is too large, consider using the [`chunk_size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) option in read_csv.

Comment: Is it possible to convert it back as a Dataframe?? how do I do it?

Comment: @YoavBarzilai It is possible to convert it to a data frame only if the number of unique values in each row are the same. If that's the case, you could do `pd.DataFrame(unique_vals)`.